truncation in R not as expected
I am having some issues while using trunc() in R (R version 4.4.0 in windows 11).
Let's say I want to trunc, for instance, this vector v <- c(.600, 1.600, 2.600, 3.600, 4.600, 5.600) to 2 decimal places. Then I do:
trunc(100*v)/100

I obtain these weird results: [1] 0.60 1.60 2.60 3.60 4.59 5.60
Why do I obtain 4.59 only in the case of 4.60?
Is there any other better way to do this truncation in R?
Thanks in advance.

Check out sprintf("%.16f", 100*v) and read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9508558/1412059

FAQ 7.31 strikes again: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f

There’s a second issue here (besides floating point arithmetic): you seem to expect trunc() to produce a specific number of decimal digits, but that’s not what it does, and can’t do: trailing 0s do not exist in the numbers. They are a feature of the representation of a number, i.e. they only exist once the number is converted to a character string. In other words: use sprintf(), not trunc(), as shown in Roland’s comment.

As Roland linked in the comments, the reason this happens is explained in
Why are these numbers not equal?
In terms of what you can do about it, one approach is to add a very small number, epsilon, scaled by a factor that is large enough to ensure that the value is pushed just past the floating-point precision threshold without altering the intended result meaningfully.
We can, for example, scale epsilon by the same factor you use for truncation to ensure that the adjustment is meaningful at the scale of the operation you're performing.
trunc_with_epsilon <- function(v, scale) {
    epsilon <- .Machine$double.eps * scale
    trunc(scale * (v + epsilon)) / scale
}

trunc_with_epsilon(v, 100)
# [1] 0.6 1.6 2.6 3.6 4.6 5.6

A word of caution though is that as the scale factor increases, the epsilon adjustment will eventually introduce new inaccuracies. In this case, this will work up to a scale of around 1e8, but at scale=1e9 you will get values like 0.60002. It is impossible to completely eliminate floating-point precision issues at larger scales because of inherent limitations of floating-point representation.
If you need arbitrary precision floating point arithmetic in R you might want to consider the Rmpfr package.

This is a good answer but would be improved by incorporating the information from the comments in your answer (comments are considered ephemeral, can be deleted at any time)

trunc() is fundamentally the wrong tool to produce a specific representation of a number, see my comment under the question.

@KonradRudolph I didn't think the question required the output to have two decimal places but if it does then of course you're right
